# paper size not proper in output pdf ghostscript

Tags: shell, pdf, command, ghostscript

I try to resize pdf by ghostscript command line but output pdf papersize not according to input i m using command gswin64c.exe -o E:\output.pdf -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dDOPDFMARKS -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=396 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=612 -f E:\comic.pdf

and output pdf size is 396 x 604.653 pts

can you help me about this issue.

Comment: Can't help without seeing the input PDF file, would also help to know the version of Ghostscript you are using. It may be that the original PDF file has a CropBox or similar.

Comment: input pdf size is 495.12x756 pts

Comment: input pdf size is 495.12x756 pts and  Ghostscript versions 9.50

Comment: With respect, I didn't ask for the input PDF 'size', I need to see the actual PDF file.

Comment: [actual pdf](http://167.172.155.215:3000/ps/comic11.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, you are trying to scale the PDF by different amounts horizontally and vertically, the PDFFitPage switch doesn't do that.

In fact there is no canned option for doing that in Ghostscript at all, you would need to write a PostScript program to do so.

If we look at your original file the page has a MediaBox of: /MediaBox[0.0 0.0 495.12 756.0], so that's (as you say) 495.12 x 756 points. You insist the output be 396x612.

So the x scale factor is 396/495.12 = 0.7998, the y scale factor is 612/756 = 0.809. So in order to scale isomorphically we need to use the scale factor of 0.7998. 756 * 0.7998 = 604.6488. Rounding errors probably explain the slight differences.

Comment: thanks for explain. i have another issue about this i m try to add crop marker with postscript but right side crop marker not on right place. right crop marker pick new width or height. here is code

Comment: thanks for explain. i have another issue about this i m try to add crop marker with postscript but right side crop marker not on right place. right crop marker pick new width or height. here is code [Output pdf link](http://167.172.155.215:3000/ps/output.pdf) i am using this code in \Endpage
/pagewidth  currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get def
/pageheight currentpagedevice /PageSize get 1 get def
/y pageheight 9 sub def
/x pagewidth 9 sub def
newpath
 x y moveto
 0 10 rlineto
 10 0 rlineto
 0 -10 rlineto
 -10 0 rlineto
 closepath
 gsave
 grestore
 1 setlinewidth
 stroke

Comment: Its probably better to ask this as another question. Remember, other people may have the same problem and its very hard to find questions buried inside other questions, which leads to duplication. Can you put the complete Ghostscript command line in your question as well please ? I'm doubtful you are actually using \EndPage because that would be a syntax error, it should be /EndPage.....